# Download csv file not working on server

Tags: php

Hello need to download generated csv file and i'm used below code but on server i'm not able to download csv file. The same code working fine in my local sytem but not working on live server.

```
<?php 
function downloadFile($filename,$filepath)
{
header("Content-type: text/csv"); // instead of pdf use others... for text 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename); 
readfile($filepath);  
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the output when you call the function? Any error messages? Are you sure the `$filepath` points to an existing file? Make sure you've got read permissions

Comment: yes filepath is for exist file.

Comment: my file have 0644 permission

Comment: This same code is working fine in my local system. But on server is not working.

Comment: Where you put $filename , Put whole path with filename@Kishan

Comment: Thanks @alex. Full path working fine

Answer (score 0):

check your server, may be there is space limitation.